# perl not recognized as a command in Windows 7

Tags: perl, antivirus, strawberry-perl

There are other posts on the forum with similar titles, but I think my problem is different and hence am posting this inquiry here.

What I encountered is the same (as other posts) in that I was "suddenly" prompted with an error message "`perl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`".

But the differences are (or so I think) -

(1) Strawberry Perl (64-bit) installed and ran well earlier.

(2) After the error message showed up, I typed `path` under `cmd` and it showed that Strawberry perl was "still" in the path (assuming my understanding of the `path` in `cmd` was correct). See at the end the full "PATH".

(3) Earlier of the day I ran a few perl scripts with no problems. Then I noticed my Panda Free Antivirus was disabled. I re-enabled it and started a full scan. It seems that right after I started the scan, the error message about perl not recognized showed up when I attempted to run another script.

Any solution as to how I could run perl scripts, assuming PATH is correctly set. (Antivirus Scan is ongoing. I know perhaps I should have waited until the scan is finished and re-test the perl module, but I wonder why anti-virus, if at all, would cause the conflict with Strawberry Perl module)

Not sure if this is a question for stackoverflow or if I should direct my question to anti-virus forum/am-I-infected forum ?

Any suggestion?

> PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Cuminas\Document Express DjVu Plug-in\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL
>   SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;

Comment: Did your antivirus find a false positive on `perl.exe` and quarantine or delete it?  Is there a `perl.exe` in `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin`?

Comment: No & Yes. So far, no antivirus did not pick up perl.exe as a suspect (scan not finished). And yes, perl.exe (perl15.22.0.exe) is still in strawberry\perl\bin

Comment: `perl.exe` and `perl5.22.0.exe` are two separate (though identical) files.  Typing "perl" will run `perl.exe`, not `perl5.22.0.exe`.  You'd have to type "perl5.22.0" to run that.

Comment: to clarify, am i supposed to have perl.exe from Strawberryperl ? a search in C: shows that there is no perl.exe. so either it's been quarantined, or it's never there to begin with. but as i never check after installing strawberryperl, it's difficult to know now if i had it at the beginning (a quick look at strawberryperl.com didn't seem to suggest perl.exe exists though)

Comment: @CJM, you are right ! It turns out antivirus DID quarantine perl.exe as a suspect. Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: I've summarized my comments as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the Strawberry Perl bin directory is still in your path, it doesn't follow that `perl.exe` is still located in that directory.  `perl.exe` and `perl5.22.0.exe` are two separate (though identical) files.  Typing "perl" will run `perl.exe`, not `perl5.22.0.exe`. You'd have to type "perl5.22.0" to run that.

The message "perl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" indicates that `perl.exe` was not found in any directory in your path.  (Or your system is so messed up it can't run `.exe` files anymore, which can happen.) So something (e.g. your antivirus) must have removed `perl.exe`.